# How to encode and perform input validation in REST API's using ESAPI

Tags: rest, esapi

How to encode and perform input validation in REST API's using ESAPI in JAVA project.

> I would also like to know how we **log**, **block** and **redirect** in case violations.
>
> I am implementing an REST application where i need to encode and validate URLs to avoid XSS and other injection attacks related to web application and URLs.

Comment: What is the input format?  XML or JSON?

Comment: Request and response body are both in JSON

Comment: You need to add more content.  When you say input validation, what are you trying to validate?  Will there be URLs being passed as data?  ESAPI is designed to be pulled into any java application, so blocking and redirecting is really more appropriate to the application framework.  What specifically are you trying to defend against?

Comment: Any links for helpful tutorial or project implemented using ESAPI will be a grate help.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_Swingset

There are guided tutorials within the application.